# Clickonce application error on mac based windows platform

Tags: macos, clickonce, hostname

I developed my application in visual studio 2008 and i deployed it on many computers with windows paltform. Its working fine but there is one mac book who has virtual windows 7 over it. my clickonce appliaction is working fine for the first time on this machine when it is installed. but after closing it when user start it again it is giving the following error. I have googled it but could not find the proper answer. Can anyone help?

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.296
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.296 (RTMGDR.030319-2900)
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of \\.psf\Home\Desktop\MyApplication.appref-ms| resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    No phase information is available.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [01/03/2013 10:58:47] System.UriFormatException
        - Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
            at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is explained in the error: "\.psf\Home\Desktop\MyApplication.appref-ms| resulted in exception". It can't parse that as a URL or a network share.

So how are you installing your application? Are you hosting it on a webserver or a fileshare, or taking it on a cd and copying it to the machine and installing it? What is your installation URL in the Publish window for the project properties?